# Obtain combined data (text + pictures) from Word::Range or Word::Selection

Tags: ms-word, com, range, interop

I can obtain text data from Word::Range with

```
Range->Text
```

and I can obtain pictures with

```
Range->InlineShapes
```

but I can't obtain both data simultaneously. So when I pick a picture, I can't tell the exact place in text where this picture is located.

Is it a way to obtain informatioin about picture position or may be a way to get continuous "Range->Text" which contains both text and pic data, as a source filename may be, like:

```
"Hello there 'C:\pics\pic.jpg' blablabla".
```

Also, when I apply Range->Text on the range, that contains both text and pic, it returns pic pos as a slash, like

```
"Hello there/blablabla"
```

but I can't tell if it denotes a picture position or just a usual slash.

Answer (score 0):

Word's object model is just that: it's based on objects. So things won't be returned as a sequence. You can sort of get that if you pick up the Word Open XML:

```
stringWordContent = range.WordOpenXML
```

Other than that, you'd need to do some comparisons on where the picture is located in relation to the text:

```
inlineShape = range.InlineShapes(1)
rangeInlineShape = inlineShape.Range
textRange = range
'to compare location
rangeInlineShape.InRange(textRange)
rangeInlineShape.Start
rangeInlineShape.End
textRange.Start
textRange.End
```